# Como imprimir o nome do Navegador ou do SO em uma JSP - Java Web

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jsp, request

gostaria de saber como imprimir o navegador que o cliente está usando e o se SO usando jsp. Algumas pessoas sugeriram usar o `${header["user-agent"]}` porém, esse comando retorna várias informações e eu gostaria apenas do navegador e do SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dê uma olhada na [user-agent-utils](http://www.bitwalker.eu/software/user-agent-utils), com essa lib você consegue facilmente extrair as informações que precisa, por exemplo:

```
String userAgentStr = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
UserAgent userAgent = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(userAgentStr);
```

E no objeto UserAgent você tem métodos como `getOperatingSystem()` e `getBrowser()`. [Javadoc aqui.](http://bitwalker.eu/user-agent-utils-snapshot/javadoc/index.html)